# freeze report Title and Tablix Header in a SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I want to Freeze report title as well as tablix header

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the bottom row of the designer which shows Row Groups and Column Groups, there is an arrow down logo at the right side. Click that then it will show Advanced Mode.

Then on the row groups. click the 1st and 2nd row then on the Properties pane. Make FixedData property into True.

Comment: "List of films" should be included into the tablix to freeze it. Just add a row above the header then merge all cells and put the "List of films" title